# How to add runtime functionality to annotation types in Java?

Tags: java, annotations, runtime

I'm trying to understand the use cases of annotations. I read e.g. the [Oracle Annotations Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html) and some other resources. One type of examples that was always missing is, how to actually add functionality for annotations.

Let's say I'd like to have an annotation `@SetValueIfNull` that assigns/returns a given value when fields, parameters or methods equal/return `null`.

My annotation could be:

```
package com.stackoverflow.tests.annotations;

/**
 * Replaces null in fields, parameters and methods.
 */
public @interface SetValueIfNull {
  /**
   * Value used to replace null.
   */
  String replacement() default "";
}
```

And here an example of it's usage:

```
package com.stackoverflow.tests.annotations;

public class ReplaceNull {

  @SetValueIfNull(replacement = "Peter")
  private String name;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReplaceNull o = new ReplaceNull();

    // This should print "Peter"
    System.out.println(o.getName());

    // This should print "Julie"
    o.setName(null);
    System.out.println(o.getName());

    // This should print "John"
    o.setName("John");
    System.out.println(o.getName());

    // This should print "Margaret"
    System.out.println(o.maggy());

  }

  String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  void setName(@SetValueIfNull(replacement = "Julie") String n) {
    this.name = n;
  }

  @SetValueIfNull(replacement = "Margaret")
  String maggy() {
    return null;
  }

}
```

The only buzzwords that popped up from time to time were "use reflection (or compiler plugins)". I guess compiler plugins are not the way to go for runtime functionality (besides that I have no idea how to write compiler plugins).

So is there an easy solution for my example or would I have to develop/use a whole framework for that?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to develop/use a whole framework.  (And even then, I wouldn't call it a good idea - annotations that do extra linguistic magic are...problematic.)